# "Bicycles 2011 community moderator election" doesn't end on a wednesday

Tags: bug, status-completed

The notification at the top of bicycles.SE says:

"The Bicycles 2011 community moderator election ends on Wednesday sep 29th"

Not only the 29th is a Thursday, but also the elections end on a Thursday.

I reckon this is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a FYI to the moderators, **every active user who has enough rep to vote gets an individual site user message for the final election phase of the election.**

So by manually adding this site message, you are notifying

- anonymous users
- users who don't have the right to vote
- users who can vote, but already got notified via a site message specific to them

Additionally, we also have a brief (as intended!) site message at the start and end of the election.

So adding yet *another* system message is redundant in all cases for the final phase of the election. I'm going to go ahead and remove this site message.

Comment: This was never communicated to us until now; thanks for the info!

Comment: not a problem, just clarifying that everyone who can vote and visits the site at *all* during the election period is definitely going to know about it, trust me :)